# Meteor user find noting returning any users in publish

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm not getting back any users in my publications, it's a bit weird. I'm pretty sure I have everything setup correctly. The console.log count is showing me 14 which is correct

```
Meteor.publish('collaborators', function() {
    console.log(Meteor.users.find().count());
    return Meteor.users.find();

});
```

Wait on function in my router

```
Meteor.subscribe('collaborators');
```

And my template

```
collaborators: function() {
    return Collaborators.find(); 
},
```

Comment: `Collaborators` vs `Meteor.users`, what are we talking about ?

Comment: collaborators is just a publish it's not a collection Meteor user is the collection. 

Just like this 
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {email: 1}});
});

Comment: So why are you returning `Collaborators.find()` like it was a collection ?

Comment: that's a mistake even if I remove it still getting noting

Comment: Ok I think I got it, Collaborators.find() was missing up everything if I just use Meteor.users.find() it's fine